# Big-O of a summation of i^k

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, runtime, big-o, complexity-theory

Say I need to calculate the time complexity of a function
**1<sup>6</sup>+2<sup>6</sup>+3<sup>6</sup>+...+n<sup>6</sup>**.  I am pretty sure this would be **O(n<sup>7</sup>)**, but I only figure that because I know that **Σi** from **i=0** to **n** is in **O(n<sup>2</sup>)**.  I cannot find a simple closed-version formula for a summation of i<sup>k</sup>.  Can anyone provide more detail on how to *actually* calculate the time complexity?

Thanks!

Comment: This is a question for math.SE. Since n^k is increasing in n, you could bound the sum between two definite integrals with nice closed forms to get an asymptotically tight bound.

Comment: What you're looking for is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula. In big-O notation, the sum of `i^k` is indeed `O(n^(k+1))` as you suspected.

Answer (score 3):

An easy proof that it's Θ(n⁷) is to observe that:

1⁶+2⁶+3⁶+...+n⁶ <= n⁶+n⁶+...n⁶ = n⁷

(replacing all numbers with n makes the sum larger).

and

1⁶+2⁶+3⁶+...+n⁶ >= (n/2+1)⁶+...+n⁶ >= (n/2)⁶+(n/2)⁶+...+(n/2)⁶ = n⁷/2⁷

(in the first step, we discard the terms less or equal than n/2, and in the second step we replace all numbers with n/2. Both steps reduce the sum). (Note: I've assumed n is even, but you can extend to odd n with a bit of minor fiddling around).

Thus 1⁶+2⁶+3⁶+...+n⁶ is bounded above and below by a constant factor of n⁷ and so by definition is Θ(n⁷).

As David Eisenstat suggests in the comments, another proof is to consider the (continuous) graphs y=x⁶ and y=(x+1)⁶ from 0 to n. The area under these curves bound the sum below and above, and are readily calculated via integrals: the first is n⁷/7 and the second is ((n+1)⁷-1)/7. This shows that the sum is n⁷/7 + o(n⁷)